# Finding the version of jetifier packaged with Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-jetifier

I am trying to use the Jetifier that comes packaged with Android Studio, to convert few 3rd party libraries to their AndroidX compatible versions.

I need to know which version of Jetifier is packaged with my Android Studio(v 3.5.2). Is there a link for the mapping of which version of Jetifier is bundled with which version of Android Studio or a gradle version?

Comment: Did you try standalone jetifier tool https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/jetifier for aar jar and zip. Otherwise use Android studio inbuilt migration tool.

Comment: Yes, I am using the Android Studio inbuilt migration tool only. But I need to know the *version* of Jetifier that is being used.

Comment: Why do you need to know the version of Jetifier being used?

Comment: So, jetifier had a issue of ResultReceiver support to AndroidX mapping for version less than 1.0.0-beta04. I have updated my Android Studio and gradle versions to latest, but I still see that issue. Need to verify if my Jetifier was also ugraded to its latest version with the fix or not.

[https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/jetifier#1.0.0-beta04]